# Power dissipation calculation

Tags: electrical-resistance

[image]
In the first circuit, the $n$ Resistors are connected in parallel and this system is in series with $R_0$.

The second circuit has $n$ resistors in series which are also in series with $R_0$. However it has been said that, both the systems of $n$ resistors give off same power (batteries are identical in both cases).

Can anyone explain explain how this is possible to get same power in both cases!?

Answer (score 0):

> However it has been said that, both the systems of $n$ resistors give
>   off same power (batteries are identical in both cases).

It has been said by *whom*?

[Ohm's law states](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/dcp_2.html) that the dissipated power $P$ for a simple closed circuit is given by:

$$P=\frac{V^2}{R}$$

Where $V$ is the voltage and $R$ the total resistance.

So let's calculate the total resistances for the left (suffix $L$) and right hand side (suffix $R$) circuits:

**1. Left:**

The resistance of the parallel part ($p$) is:

$$\frac{1}{R_p}=\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{R_i}=\frac{n}{R}$$
$$R_p=\frac{R}{n}$$
The total resistance becomes:
$$R_L=R_0+R_p=R_0+\frac{R}{n}$$
And the power dissipated on the left:
$$P_L=\frac{E^2}{R_L}=\frac{E^2}{R_0+\frac{R}{n}}$$
**2. Right:**

The total resistance is:
$$R_R=R_0+nR$$
The power dissipated on the right:

$$P_R=\frac{E^2}{R_R}=\frac{E^2}{R_0+nR}$$

**Clearly:**

$$P_L\neq P_R$$

The only way to equalise power dissipation is to adjust voltage but the problem states:

> batteries are identical in both cases

It strikes me though that in the image, the truncated symbol for the voltage of the left hand side does not resemble an $E$. Might the question have been about finding a voltage, say $D$, for the left hand side, so that $P_L=P_R$:

$$\frac{D^2}{R_0+\frac{R}{n}}=\frac{E^2}{R_0+nR}$$

So that:

$$D=E\sqrt\frac{R_0+\frac{R}{n}}{R_0+nR}$$